# How flatten a dataframe with dates to make difference ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this piece of df:

```
date_time                       value
2019-07-03 16:23:37.006155      406     
2019-07-03 16:28:37.640527      460     
2019-07-03 16:28:47.782197      405     
2019-07-03 16:30:49.381823      460     
2019-07-03 16:30:59.514452      405     
2019-07-03 16:32:35.733175      460
```

As you can see, there are a lot of sequence with minimum and maximum value. I would like to transform my df into the dataframe belows:

```
date_time                       value   date_time2                   value2
2019-07-03 16:23:37.006155      406     2019-07-03 16:28:37.640527   460
2019-07-03 16:28:47.782197      405     2019-07-03 16:30:49.381823   460
2019-07-03 16:30:59.514452      405     2019-07-03 16:32:35.733175   460
```

The goal is to make the difference between the two dates conserving value and value2 in one row.

### **YOUR RESULT**

```
date_time   value   date_time2  id  value2
0   2019-07-03 16:28:47.782197      405.0   2019-07-03 16:23:37.006155      406
1   2019-07-03 16:30:59.514452      405.0   2019-07-03 16:28:37.640527      460
2   2019-07-03 16:34:22.071005      460.0   2019-07-03 16:30:49.381823      460
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are concatting `odd` rows to the right? You could use `pd.concat` to concat two dataframes (one with even rows and one with odd rows) and pass `axis=1`. You can use `df.index % 2 == 0` to filter for even and `df.index % 2 == 1` to filter for odd. You'll also need to make sure you `use` reset_index()`, or they will not` concat` on the same lines since different indices without a reset:

```
df = df.sort_values('date_time')
df = pd.concat([df[df.index % 2 == 0].reset_index(drop=True), 
                df[df.index % 2 == 1].rename({'date_time' : 'date_time2', 'value' : 'value2'}, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
                    date_time  value                  date_time2  value2
0  2019-07-03 16:23:37.006155    406  2019-07-03 16:28:37.640527     460
1  2019-07-03 16:28:47.782197    405  2019-07-03 16:30:49.381823     460
2  2019-07-03 16:30:59.514452    405  2019-07-03 16:32:35.733175     460
```

Comment: I think there is a problem in your code because, the result is different 1row 405-406

Comment: @ThonyNadhir I have matched the output in your question.

Comment: I copied and pasted yours and executed but the result is not what I expected.

There is a lag, see my new post

Comment: @ThonyNadhir it looks like your dataframe may be unsorted where you are running your code? Can you try the code but add `df = df.sort_values('date_time')`?

Comment: I already use `sort_velue`. It seems, it's because of the processing I do upstream, the index is no longer good, so to correct I reset the index. Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: @ThonyNadhir no problem kindly upvote if helpful. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

data.csv:

```
date time                       value
2019-07-03 16:23:37.006155      406     
2019-07-03 16:28:37.640527      460     
2019-07-03 16:28:47.782197      405     
2019-07-03 16:30:49.381823      460     
2019-07-03 16:30:59.514452      405     
2019-07-03 16:32:35.733175      460
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter='\s+')

df1 = df.loc[df.index % 2 == False].reset_index()
df2 = df.loc[df.index % 2 == True].reset_index()
print(df1)
print(df2)
res = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
   index        date             time  value
0      0  2019-07-03  16:23:37.006155    406
1      2  2019-07-03  16:28:47.782197    405
2      4  2019-07-03  16:30:59.514452    405
   index        date             time  value
0      1  2019-07-03  16:28:37.640527    460
1      3  2019-07-03  16:30:49.381823    460
2      5  2019-07-03  16:32:35.733175    460
   index        date             time  value  index        date             time  value
0      0  2019-07-03  16:23:37.006155    406      1  2019-07-03  16:28:37.640527    460
1      2  2019-07-03  16:28:47.782197    405      3  2019-07-03  16:30:49.381823    460
2      4  2019-07-03  16:30:59.514452    405      5  2019-07-03  16:32:35.733175    460
```

Comment: df2.rename(columns = {'index':'index2','date' : 'date2', 'time': 'time2', 'value' : 'value2'}, inplace = True)

Comment: Hi @AajKaal , this is very similar to my answer, so I am not sure if you saw that I already posted.

Comment: Also, when resetting the index, you pass `drop=True` in case you didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to slice the dataframe into even/odd rows by using `iloc`. You can use `join` to stick them together while also adding the proper suffix in 1 step as well.

```
df_even, df_odd = [df.iloc[i::2].reset_index(drop=True) for i in (0, 1)]
out = df_even.join(df_odd, rsuffix="2")
​
print(out)
                    date_time  value                  date_time2  value2
0  2019-07-03 16:23:37.006155    406  2019-07-03 16:28:37.640527     460
1  2019-07-03 16:28:47.782197    405  2019-07-03 16:30:49.381823     460
2  2019-07-03 16:30:59.514452    405  2019-07-03 16:32:35.733175     460
```